# Angularjs ng-click event on ajax-loaded element not firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having trouble getting a click event to fire from some content that is loaded via ajax. Not seeing either console.log from the following code:

```
myApp.controller("MainController", function($scope, $http, $sce){
    $scope.showModal = false;
    $scope.openModal = function(name){
        $scope.showModal = true;
        $http({
            method : 'GET',
            url : '/template/fetch?name=' + name
        }).success(function(modalHtml){
            $scope.modalHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(modalHtml);

            $scope.closeModal = function(){
                console.log("test 2");
            };

        });
    };

    $scope.closeModal = function(){
        console.log("test 1");
    };

});
```

And here is the html that is loaded via ajax:

```
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-cover">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-container">
        <div class="modal-close" ng-click="closeModal()"></div>
        <div class="modal-content-container" ng-bind-html="modalContent">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: The html loaded via ajax won't work like you would do via jquery.  You'll want to either write a directive or do some kind of ngInclude that has the html for your modal.

Comment: You never posted your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way I believe is to employ `ngInclude` directive and use your template url as `src` value of this direcive:

```
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-cover">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-container">
      <div class="modal-close" ng-click="closeModal()"></div>
      <div class="modal-content-container" ng-include src='modalContentUrl'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And controller's code:

```
  $scope.modalContentUrl = '';

  $scope.openModal = function(name) {
    $scope.showModal = true;
    $scope.modalContentUrl = '/template/fetch?name=' + name;
  };
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vUEV1tUfILG9WtRSzTUl?p=preview)