# ng-click not working for datatable ajax data

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, datatables

I'm using datatable jquery to generate table and with the help of AJAX in datatable.

My table is generated successfully but in that one column has ng-click funtion and when i click on that its not working i mean its not going to controller.

Output is : 
[image]
Here is my code :

Controller:

```
'use strict';

app.controller('AdminController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state','sessionService', function($scope, $http, $state, sessionService) {
    $scope.authError = null;
    $scope.loading = false ; 
    $scope.tbOptions = {
        data: [],
        sAjaxSource: 'api/api.php?type=admin_users',
        aoColumns: [
            { mData: 'no' },
            { mData: 'name' },
            { mData: 'email' },
            { mData: 'role' },
            { mData: 'action' }
        ],
        aoColumnDefs: [
            {
                aTargets: [4],
                mRender: function (data, type, full) {
                    var tbAction = '';
                    tbAction += '<button type="button" ng-click="editAdmin('+full.id+')" class="btn btn-xs btn-default"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>';
                    tbAction += '&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                    tbAction += '<button type="button" ng-click="deleteAdmin('+full.id+')" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>';
                    return tbAction;
                }  
            }
        ]
    };
    $scope.editAdmin = function(id){
        console.log('S-'+id);
    }

    $scope.deleteAdmin = function(id){
        console.log('S-'+id);
    }
}]);
```

HTML View :

```
<div class="bg-light lter b-b wrapper-md">
  <h1 class="m-n font-thin h3">Admin User List</h1>
</div>
<div class="wrapper-md">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      Admin User
    </div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table ui-jq="dataTable" ui-options="tbOptions" class="table table-striped b-t b-b" ng-controller="AdminController" ajax-datatable>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th  style="width:20%">No.</th>
            <th  style="width:25%">Name</th>
            <th  style="width:25%">Email</th>
            <th  style="width:15%">Role</th>
            <th  style="width:15%">Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Directive :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app')
  .directive('ajaxDatatable', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function(html) {
        ele.html(html);
        $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: can you provide plunker

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/QrCytr6WDVeCei7Bv25p

Comment: plunker not working

Comment: When you have HTML that is dynamically inserted like this you need to use the `$compile` service manually to link the `ng-click` to a specific scope. If you get a plunker working that is populating the table I can show you an example of how.

Comment: Actully i'm not familier with plunker can you just tell me about that `$compile`. i mean what i need to add in my controller.@tasseKATT

Comment: @tasseKATT i have added `$compile` and directive for it please check it and let me know its right or worng..

Comment: you can check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470853/angularjs-ng-click-event-on-ajax-loaded-element-not-firing

Comment: Its done...thanks @tasseKATT

Comment: The Plunkr is not working, and I am having the same issue.  I have tried to manipulate the plunkr to work, and cant seem to get that running either. can someone post a working plunkr?